# How to add a new string to an array in a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I have a profile.json file and I want to be able to make it so when you do a certain command, it adds the argument you input to the array. like so

```
{"Profile_name":"id":"idhere", "array":["item_1"]}
```

I want to be able to add more items to that array when a user uses the command to do so

Comment: There is syntax array in the definition. `"id":"idhere"` doesn't make any sense. The colon cannot be there. To add items to an array use `push(item)` method.

Answer (score 0):

First, u have syntax error in your json.

Second, u ask for ready code.

Third, here, u have scrap that you can start with:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

// read file
let my_json = fs.readFileSync(path_to_file);
my_json = JSON.parse(my_json);

// edit variable here
// for example
my_json.array.push("new item");

// write file
my_json = JSON.stringify(my_json);
fs.writeFileSync(path_to_file, my_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file, push new element to array and then save the file

```
const fs = require('fs');
//reads the file
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('file.json');
//convert to JSON object
let json = JSON.parse(rawdata);
//Before: {"Profile_name":"name","id":"idhere", "array":["item_1"]}
json["array"].push("more");
//After: {"Profile_name":"name","id":"idhere", "array":["item_1","more"]}
//Convert to string
let data = JSON.stringify(json);
//Save the file
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', data);
```

Comment: json["array"].push("more"); this line tries to access "array" and in your case it does not exist.